# Convert SQL, but return different results

Tags: sql

this is the original SQL, that works very well.

```
select a.sessionid
from session a
left
outer
join applicationinfo b
on a.sessionid=b.sessionid
left
outer
join license c
on a.sessionid=c.sessionid
limit 10
;
```

below is the converted SQL

```
SELECT s.sessionid
FROM  
( SELECT *
  FROM session  a
  LEFT
  OUTER
  JOIN applicationinfo  b
  ON (a.sessionid = b.sessionid)
)s
LEFT
OUTER
JOIN license c
ON (s.sessionid = c.sessionid)
limit 10
;
```

the second SQL will get 10 NULLs. Since those tables are left joined on the sessionid field. Suppose in the second SQL the s.sessionid should not be NULL.

Could someone tell me the reason why those two SQL cannot return the same result. Thanks.

Comment: Because they are different queries. What is the `s.sessionid` ? `a.sessionid` or `b.sessionid`?

Comment: That's what happens when you use `limit` without an `order by` clause.

Comment: Let me guess, MySQL? That query shouldn't even run since both `a` and `b` have (at least) both got a `sessionid` column, so the `select *` in the subquery should have a problem because it has multiple columns with the same name.

Comment: Completely different logic being used. Second SQL runs from select and than left joins to license.

Comment: Hive, which is based on hadoop, the second is generate/auto-convert by ODBC from the first one. Hive can return the expected result with the first SQL, but return NULLs for the generated second SQL.